# SwiftPM Package building target in docker

Tags: swift, docker, swiftpm

Im trying to setup an external library in a SwiftPM Package project. This package ([Mockingbird](https://github.com/birdrides/mockingbird)) is only used from within my test target, and therefor my main application target does not depend on this.

On my MacOS host machine, building and executing this test target works perfectly fine. No errors whatsoever.

However, i'm also building this application within a dockerized container within a CI process. Im using the official swift docker images (swift 5.5) for this.

From within this docker container, building the main target itself works fine, because it does not depends on the Mockingbird lib. But building the test target fails when compiling mockingbird.

When starting this Docker container, i always clean the build folder and resolve the packages first before building the targets.

This is the error im getting:

```
In file included from /app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/MKBTypeFacade.m:1:
/app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/../include/MKBTypeFacade.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/MKBTestExpectation.m:1:
/app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/../include/MKBTestExpectation.h:1:9: fatal error: 'XCTest/XCTest.h' file not found
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/MKBTestUtils.m:1:
/app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/../include/MKBTestUtils.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/MKBMocking.m:1:
/app/.build/checkouts/mockingbird/Sources/MockingbirdFramework/Objective-C/Bridge/sources/../include/MKBMocking.h:1:9: fatal error: 'Foundation/Foundation.h' file not found
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

---

Maybe im missing out on something?
Thanks in advance!

---

Edit 1: Added dockerfile

```
FROM swift:5.6.2-focal


WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install openssh-client lcov -y

ARG INSTALL_COMMANDS="echo \"No custom install commands provided, proceeding\""
RUN ${INSTALL_COMMANDS}

ARG GITLAB_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir -p ~/.ssh \
    && echo "${GITLAB_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" \
    && ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
    && ssh-keyscan ${GIT_URL} > ~/.ssh/known_hosts

## Copy entire repo into container
COPY ./Package.* ./
RUN swift package resolve

COPY . .

## Remove SSH keys
RUN rm -rf /root/.ssh/
```

---

After my image was created containing the source files, i run it like:

```
docker run ${IMAGE_NAME} \
    /bin/sh -c "swift build --target AppTests"
```

Comment: Could you share your `Dockerfile`? And/or the way you're creating the container?

Comment: Thanks for responding! I added my dockerfile and how i start this container. Looks like nothing special here, although i tried using multiple different source images from swift (like centos and bionice).

Maybe im missing out on something? I know this library uses some Objective-c within its framework we're it relies on.

Comment: Can you `docker exec` in your container and check the contents of `Package.resolved` to see if the dependencies resolved as expected?

Comment: There were no errors whatsoever resolving the dependencies and the packages are resolved correctly in the .build folder. Also, the .build folder is within my .dockerignore file, so the build folder is clean when creating the image.

Comment: Try including it in your image. It appears these dependencies are being searched in `/app/.build`.

Comment: Will try tomorrow thanks! However, when in a CI pipeline, the .build folder is not there since this will not be included on the git repo.

Comment: Okay, i figured out this library simply doesnt work in Linux unfortunately. Had some help from the Swift forum to confirm this: https://forums.swift.org/t/building-swiftpm-package-in-docker/58797/3

Comment: Ah, sad to hear that :( Perhaps there's an alternative library that is more portable.

Comment: Ye ended up writing my own micro framework for creating mocks/stubs. Works fine :)

Comment: Great! Glad it worked out.